# Spring batch read from parquet file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, parquet

I am trying to read parquet file in Spring Batch Job and write is to JDBC. Is there any sample code for `reader` bean which can be used in springframework batch `StepBuilderFactory`?

Comment: I couldn't find any example but I know that `parquet-mr` (https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr) provides Java APIs to read/write parquet files, you can use these APIs to create a Spring Batch item reader for this format.

Answer (score 1):

Spring for Apache Hadoop has capabilities for reading and writing Parquet files.  You can read more about that project here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-hadoop

Comment: This library is deprecated since new versions of Spring don't support it.

Comment: So no spring support available to read parquet file in Spring batch ?